# Can I determine hydraulic load on river bank with hec-ras?

Tags: modelling, rivers, hec-ras

I want to calculate the force exerted by wave action on river bank.

If I know the discharge, flow rate and water level, can I calculate the hydraulic load acting on river bank with hec-ras?

If not, how can I do this?

Comment: This is not the place to post this question. This is a forum for GIS questions, not hydraulic models. Also, discharge==flow rate, and it's not clear what you mean by "hydraulic load". Shear stress?

Comment: I found some questions here related to hec-ras. So, I thought, someone can give answer to my question. If you tell me, where I can post this question, that would be very helpful for me. Here, hydraulic load means the force generated by the velocity of water. @Jon

Comment: Well, perhaps I am wrong. I don't know where else to ask, I would just use google or read the manual: http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/documentation/HEC-RAS_4.1_Reference_Manual.pdf

Comment: The HEC-RAS questions on here generally relate to getting GIS-related data into and out of the program, or to using the built-in Rasmapper GIS interface. Your question is pure hydrology, though. There are a few forums out there for HEC-RAS users, and some decent tutorials as well; just keep on looking, I'm sure you'll find it.